# Discrete harmonic functions bounded from below.

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, random-walk, harmonic-functions

> Given $n\in \mathbb N$, describe the set of all the discrete harmonic functions $f:\mathbb Z^n \to \mathbb R_+$.

A function $f:\mathbb Z^n\to \mathbb R$ is harmonic iff
$$
  2nf(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n [f(x-e_i)+f(x+e_i)],
$$
for all $x\in \mathbb Z^n$,
where $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb Z^n$. Note that $f$ is discrete harmonic iff $f$ is a martingale w.r.t. a symmetric random walk on $\mathbb Z^n$.

It was [argued that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890250/discrete-harmonic-function-problem?rq=1) for $n=2$ all the discrete harmonic functions are constant. However, that assumes that $f$ is bounded from both below and above. Is the lower bound sufficient to eliminate all the non-constant functions?

For $n=1$ it is easy to show that $f$ has to be constant as all the discrete harmonic functions on $\mathbb Z$ need to have constant growth, so if $f$ was not constant it would have to be unbounded from both below and above. However, for $n=2$, the set of discrete harmonic functions on $\mathbb Z^2$ is much more rich.

**Similar:** [A discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961771/a-harmonic-function-bounded-from-below-is-constant?rq=1) of the related question for (not discrete) harmonic functions.

Comment: I found a perfect answer to this question among the answers to the related question for $n=2$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51926/a-stronger-version-of-discrete-liouvilles-theorem. Should I delete this question, or can someone mark it as a duplicate?